# How to run a command on localhost to define variable for an Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm very new to Ansible and trying to figure things out. I have a simple playbook to run on a remote host. To simplify drastically:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  name: build render VM
  tasks:
    - copy:
        src: ./project_{{ project_id }}.yaml
        dest: /app/project.yaml
        owner: root
```

I would like to have `project_id` set to the output of this command, run on localhost: `gcloud config get-value project`. Ideally I'd like that to be stored into a variable or fact that can be used throughout the playbook. I know I can pass `project_id=$(...)` on the ansible cmd line, but I'd rather have it set up automatically in the playbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking for granted the given command only returns the id and nothing else.

With a task delegated to localhost:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  name: build render VM
  tasks:
    - name: get project id
      command: gcloud config get-value project
      register: gcloud_cmd
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: set project id
      set_fact:
        project_id: "{{ gcloud_cmd.stdout }}"

    - copy:
        src: ./project_{{ project_id }}.yaml
        dest: /app/project.yaml
        owner: root
```

With a [`pipe` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pipe_lookup.html):

```yaml
- hosts: all
  name: build render VM
  tasks:

    - name: set project id from localhost command
      set_fact:
        project_id: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'gcloud config get-value project') }}"
      run_once: true

    - copy:
        src: ./project_{{ project_id }}.yaml
        dest: /app/project.yaml
        owner: root
```